# How to BLINK a <DIV> according to database data (json)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this code to get the data from database as a json file and then loop through an item (portOn) to find out which port is in the array. If it's in the array, then port is true.

```
var portG01,portG02 = false;

 const getDevices = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}`);
    const json = await response.json();
    setData(json);

    for (let i in json) {
      Object.values(json[i].portOn.split(",")).forEach((value) => {
        if (value === "G01") {
          portG01 = true;
        }
        if (value === "G02") {
          portG02 = true;
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

and then it will show the data in return like this:

```
return (
    <div className="container">
        <div className="devices">
          <div id="portG01"></div>
          <div id="portG02"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
```

Now what I want to do is to BLINK each DIV that is TRUE. How can I achieve that with CSS?
for example if the value is true then use the following CSS:

```
.blink {
    animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
  }

  @keyframes blinker {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

if not true then follow another CSS property. Please advice what would be the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the selector that will blink, then just adding dynamically the class:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const API_URL = '<your-api-url-here>';
const availableDevices = [ 'G01', 'G02' ];

export default function Component(props) {
  const [selectors, setSelectors] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getDevices().then(setSelectors);
  }, []);

  async function getDevices() {
    const response = await fetch(API_URL);
    const json = await response.json();
    const set = new Set(Object
      .values(json)
      .map(value => value.portOn.split(','))
      .flat()
      .filter(e => availableDevices.includes(e))
    );
    
    return [ ...set ];
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="devices">
        {availableDevices.map(device => (<div key={device} id={`port${device}`} className={selectors.includes(device) ? 'blink' : ''}></div>))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And, to the animation be a bit more smooth you can change your CSS to:

```css
.blink {
  animation: blinker 2s ease-in infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  0%, 100% {
    opacity: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the style (css animation) to the .blink div that needs to blink using javascript!

`document.getElementById("blink").style.animation = "animation: blinker 1s linear infinite";`

Let me know if it works!

Comment: `document.getElementById` with `.blink` in the selector will return `null` (in this particular case).

Comment: Do I need any condition for this? like true/false condition?